# Returning the largest element in an array

Tags: c, arrays, iteration

```
/* return the largest element in map[size][size] */
double map_max(size_t size, double **map) {
double max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        if (max < map[]) {
                max = map[];
          }
       }
   }

    return max;
}
```

would this work to return the largest element in map[][]? (would also do the same thing but for the smallest element)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `if (max < map[])` where are your indices? (i.e. what element should this compare to?)

Answer (score 1):

Your map lookups don't seem to have subscripts, and you're missing a semicolon on the declaration of `max`. There's also a risk that the maximum value in the array is less than 0, in which case your function will return 0 instead of the true maximum. You can fix this by either redefining max to take on some default value (say, `map[0][0]` or negative infinity).

Otherwise, provided that the array dimensions are `size` by `size`, yes, this will find the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

`map[]` is not valid syntax.  You need to index the array properly.

```
    if (max < map[i][j]) {
        max = map[i][j];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't if every array element is less than zero.

You can initialize `max` with `map[0][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

To step through a 2d array, you need two for loops as you did. The proper syntax to return the value of row i, column j from 2d array map is `map[i][j]`.

```
/* return the largest element in map[size][size] */
double map_max(size_t size, double **map) {
    double max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (map[i][j] > max) {
                max = map[i][j];
            }
         }
    }
    return max;
}
```